# Aframe Load lightmap after loading GLTF - lightmap not showing

Tags: three.js, aframe, light, gltf

I'm trying to add a lightmap to some mesh after loading them from a GLTF file.
All my objects have 2UV channel.

I'm waiting 'object3dset' and here is my code :

```
    const mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    textureLoader.load("lightmap.png", function(lmap){

        mesh.traverse((node) => {

            if (!node.isMesh) return;

            node.material.lightMap = lmap;
            lmap.flipY = node.material.map.flipY; //needed to flip the texture

            node.material.needsUpdate = true;

          });
    });
```

If I replace the material with a new one and set the lightmap, it's working.
But I want to find a way without recreating all materials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lightmap was loaded, but not easy to see. 
By default metalness from Khronos Blender Exporter converted in threejs after loading GLTF result to a level 1.0. With this configuration, the lightmap is hard to see and is not corresponding to what we see in Blender.

I hope my mistake can help someone else losing too much time.

Comment: If you've set MetallicFactor on glTF Blender exporter's custom Cycles nodes and it isn't exporting correctly, could you file a bug as well?

Comment: Hi Mano. Can you please advise how you solved "By default metalness from Khronos Blender Exporter converted in threejs after loading GLTF result to a level 1.0"

Comment: Also how you added "2UV channel" to all your objects?